# Blackberry PRIV gets reset suddenly

Tags: blackberry

I am mad and sad at the same moment when I saw that my whole phone got reset (blackberry PRIV). I lost all my personal data. It happened while as usual I was trying to play songs with out picking up my phone from my pocket using 'OK Google' feature. It played a song first but when I try again it didn't. I kept on trying for like 10 or more times. And just after like 5 mins when I checked the phone, it showed me a prompt asking whether I want to use Google launcher or blackberry launcher. When I selected blackberry launcher, it loaded the default apps. I was shocked and realised that my whole data is lost including installed apps.

Can someone please tell me what might have happened? And also I don't think there is any way but could I restore the data somehow?

Note: For each "OK Google" try, I need to press power button to wake up the phone.

Comment: Somehow I went under guest user account :/. Just switched to my account now and found all my data. TIL, we can have multiple user accounts on phone. Will delete this post after you guys take this as a lesson or a good laugh.

Comment: Please don't delete the post, because it might be helpful to other people in a similar situation. Write up how you spotted that it was a guest account and how you switched back, and post it as an answer to the question. A couple of days later you can "accept" your own answer, so that others can see the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow (maybe because of mis-hearing of "OK Google" feature), I went under guest user account :/. Just switched to my account now and found all my data. TIL, we can have multiple user accounts on phone.

When I was in guest account there was no notification or anything explaining the same and hence my havoc of losing all data started. After asking the question here and when the device was asleep, I got a notification stating something related to accounts and that I am in guest account. That gave me hope and when I just swiped from top, I could see on top right, just adjacent to battery percentage, the guest's profile picture. When I just tapped on it, it showed me available user accounts. I switched to my user account and found my data.

#### Not related:

When I was in the sad state of belief that I lost my data, I first tried to ask on official site of Blackberry and even after finding the forum site, I couldn't able to find a simple "ask question" like similar button. I can't believe that a million dollar company like BlackBerry can't afford to have a intuitive / user friendly site which is the only primary touch by which people can contact with them. It is a shameful fact for such an esteemed organisation. Hope they read this at some point and feel ashamed. I have many complaints with Blackberry's site, as I visit it frequently being a Blackberry fan, but I do understand that this is not the place to talk about it.

I don't know where exactly else I could have taken out my frustration. Since, I only find this site as intuitive. Thanks!